# Show image next to text with IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The following script shows an image next to some text.  It doesn't work with IE7. How should it be modified? Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">

    div {width:200px}
    div span {
        padding: 0 5px 0 30px;
        background-image: url("bg.gif");
        background-position:center; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    }

</style> 


<body>
    <div>Text 1<span></span></div>
    <div>Text 2<span></span></div>
    <div>Text 3<span></span></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified a doctype in the html page? 
e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Maybe IE doesn't like the empty span, try this:`<span>&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: No, IE doesn't like the empty span!  Do you want to update your answer for future viewers.  Regardless, you are right.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
div, div > span{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

I've provided A small bit of script based on your problem, browser issue and html. I'd recommend putting this code within a HTML IE7 condition:

```
<!--[if IE7]-->
    <!-- your CSS here -->
<!--[endif]-->
```

This will remove the CSS for all over browsers.

Comment: Thanks Beneto.  IE7 shows the image under the text, and all other browsers don't even show the image.

Comment: oh ok, well the code above will show the image next to the text in ie7. You said above that the elements are inserted using query? how are you doing that as that may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I shouldn't use background image.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div img.image {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

</style> 


<body>
    <div><span>Text 1</span><img class="image" src="bg.gif" /></div>
    <div><span>Text 2</span><img class="image" src="bg.gif" /></div>
    <div><span>Text 3</span><img class="image" src="bg.gif" /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't meet my needs.  The span's are inserted by a jQuery plugin, and I cannot (don't want to) just change them to images.